# How do I make sure username is not repeated in my database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I`m trying to make sure that the username value stored in my database is not repeating, and if it is repeated, a toast will inform the user that the username is already taken, how can I do so?

My DBAdapter:

```
package com.nyp.reddot5;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter 
{
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // PartyItems table name
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "login";

    // PartyItems Table Columns names
    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String EMAIL = "email";

    // Variable to hold the database instance
    public  SQLiteDatabase db;
    // Context of the application using the database.
    private final Context context;
    // Database open/upgrade helper
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
    {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close() 
    {
        db.close();
    }

    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
    {
        return db;
    }





    public void insertEntry(String userName,String password, String email)
    {
       ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);
        newValues.put("EMAIL", email);

        // Insert the row into your table
        db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
        ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
    {
        //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
        String where="USERNAME=?";
        int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;
       // Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
    }   
    public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
    {
        Cursor cursor=db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;                
    }
    public void  updateEntry(String userName,String password)
    {




    // Define the updated row content.
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

        String where="USERNAME = ?";
        db.update("LOGIN",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});               
    }
```

My SignUPActivity

```
package com.nyp.reddot5;

import com.nyp.reddot5.R;
import com.nyp.reddot5.R.id;
import com.nyp.reddot5.R.layout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignUPActivity extends Activity 
{
EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword, editTextEmail;
Button btnCreateAccount, tcbutton, backb;
CheckBox TCcb;
Context mcursor;

LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);


    tcbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tcbutton);
    backb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.backb);

    // get Instance  of Database Adapter
    loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();



    // Get Refferences of Views
    editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
    editTextEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    TCcb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.TCcb);



    btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);
    btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
        String email=editTextEmail.getText().toString();

        // check if any of the fields are vaccant
        if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals(""))
        {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }
        // check if both password matches
        if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }


        if(editTextUserName.getText().toString().length() < 7){
            editTextUserName.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required_user));
        }
        if(editTextPassword.getText().toString().length() < 5){
            editTextPassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required_pw));
        }
        if(TCcb.isChecked() == false){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You must agree to the terms and conditions!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else
        {
            // Save the Data in Database
            loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, password, email);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});

     tcbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                /// Create Intent for SignUpActivity  and Start The Activity
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TCActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            });


        backb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            /// Create Intent for SignUpActivity  and Start The Activity
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the UNIQUE constraint to the user name field in you DB. That way you make sure all values in the collumn are different (you can achieve the same thing making it PK but maybe your ussing another primary key). As for the toast, Im not sure which exception is thrown when the unique constraint is broken, but you should catch that exception, infomr the UI tier and throw the toast.

Answer (score 1):

It throws a SQLiteConstraintException:

```
try{
   db.insertOrThrow("LOGIN", null, newValues); // the normal insert may not throw an error
}catch(SQLiteConstraintException e){
 Toast.makeText(context(), "User already on database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: I`m trying to validate it in the onClick function of my SignUPActivity instead, I just added the codes above. Could you please give some advices?